# Configuring simple service with systemd

Tags: debian, systemd, configuration, services

We are using Bamboo server for continues integration with remote agents which are building our projects. These agent can be started up with a simple shell script (which  works fine). But I thought I will move it even further and make it `systemd` unit which will make agent autostart after boot and it will allow people to start/stop it via `systemctl` commands. So this what I have tried

```
[Unit]
Description=Atlassian Bamboo Agent
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=shub
Group=shub
ExecStart=/home/shub/bamboo-agent-home/bin/bamboo-agent.sh start
ExecStop=/home/shub/bamboo-agent-home/bin/bamboo-agent.sh stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Than I have done `systemctl daemon-reload`. Problem is that agent is not started up after reboot and also it's acting weird (in a way that service is restarting itself from time to time or don't come up properly after `systemctl start`). So what am I doing wrong? I thought about changing `Type` to `simple` however I want to agent run as a background service (and script itself runs agent on the background after execution).

Comment: `Type=simple` still runs as a background service, it just means that the service doesn't daemonize itself.

Comment: Ok, so which one is more suitable for my use case? And can it explain the weird behaviour I am experiencing?

Comment: forking is likely correct in your case. If it was not, `systemctl start` would never return because it would wait for the service to fork indefinitely. You haven't provided enough information (eg logs) to diagnose your issues.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that description is kinda vague. However, shouldn't service come up after reboot with this configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You asked multiple questions. I'll answer the question: "Why doesn't my custom systemd service start at boot?"

The answer is because you haven't *enabled* it. When you run `systemctl enable my-service-name`, The `[Install]` block in your Unit file is acted upon.

In this case, you have instructed systemd to start up the service as part of reaching the `multi-user.target`.

Running `enable` command will create a symlink in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/` and the presence of that symlink is what will actually instruct `systemd` to start the service upon boot.

I suggest turning your "acting weird" comment into a separate question where more detail is provided, perhaps with details from the systemd journal about what's going on. (check `journalctl` output).